# YUI3 Plugin.base not rendering

Tags: javascript, plugins, yui, yui3

I'm trying to use a yui plugin that pulls from a json file and populates a div on the page. Everything should be a go, however, since the plugin never gets to the render stage, the rest of it does not run. It is successfully loaded otherwise (if I stick an alert or console.log at the beginning of the event, it works fine).

Here's the code:

```
YUI.add('events', function(Y) {

   var urlEvents = //"/cgi-bin/eventview-json/?cal=admissions/events&days=10";
                       "/admissions/events/events.json";

   //var eventContainer = $("#insert-events");
   /* EventList class constructor */
   var EventList = function(config) {
      EventList.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
   };

   /*
    * Required NAME static field, to identify the class and
    * used as an event prefix, to generate class names etc. (set to the
    * class name in camel case).
    */
   EventList.NAME = "EventList";

   /*
    * Required NS static field, to identify the property on the host which will,
    * be used to refer to the plugin instance ( e.g. host.feature.doSomething() )
    */
   EventList.NS = "EventList";

   /*
    * The attribute configuration for the plugin. This defines the core user facing state of the plugin
    */
   EventList.ATTRS = {};


   var convertYYYYMMDDtoJS = function(s) {

      var a, jsdate = null;

      try {

         a = /^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/.exec(s);

         if (a) {
            jsdate = new Date(a[1], a[2]-1, a[3]);
         }
      } catch (ex) {
         /* Nothing */
      }

      return jsdate;
   };


   var insertEvents = function(id, response, e) {
    alert('hello');
      var i, resp, events, event, html, jsdate, label, seenevent, yyyymmdd;
      var maxevents = 5, eventcount;

      try {
         resp = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText);
         events = resp.results;

         html = "";
         seenevent = {};
         eventcount = 0;
         yyyymmdd = "";
         for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            event = events[i];
            if (seenevent[event.title]) {
               continue;
            }
            seenevent[event.title] = true;

            if (event.date !== yyyymmdd) {
               // This is the first event on this date.

               // If we've seen maxevents events, then bail before starting a new day.
               if (eventcount >= maxevents) {
                  break;
               }

               // Put out a new label for this day.
               jsdate = convertYYYYMMDDtoJS(event.date);
               label = Y.DataType.Date.format(jsdate, {format: "%b %e %a"});

               /*
                * The first empty div below, "<div class='clear'></div>" is only needed for IE 7.
                * IE 7 does not properly clear both left and right floats when "clear: both" is specified
                * if the element itself is floated.  The extra div clears the floats, but isn't floated
                * itself.  The extra div doesn't cause any grief in newer browsers, so I add it always.
                */
               html += "<div class='clear'></div><div class='event-datelabel'>" + label + "</div>\n";
               yyyymmdd = event.date;
            }

            html += "<div class='event-text'>" + event.html + "</div>\n";
                        eventcount++;
         }
         this.get('host').setContent(html + "<div id='events-footer'><a href='/calendar/'>all events</a></div>");


      } catch(ex) {
         console.log("Error", ex);
         this.get('host').setContent("Event list not available");
         return;
      }
   };


var insertEventList = function(yyyy, mm, dd) {

   var url = urlEvents;

   if (yyyy) {
      url += '&yyyy=' + yyyy;
   }
   if (mm) {
      url += '&mm=' + mm;
   }
   if (dd) {
      url += '&dd=' + dd;
   }

   Y.io(url, {on: {success: insertEvents}, context: this});

};

   /* EventList extends the base Plugin.Base class */
   Y.extend(EventList, Y.Plugin.Base, {
        render: function() {
        insertEventList.call(this);
    }

   });
   //console.log("assigning", EventList);
   Y.namespace("Plugin").EventList = EventList;

}, '1.0.0' ,{requires:['node', 'base', 'plugin', "json-parse", "datatype-date"]});
```

Here's the excerpt from the code with the render bit:

```
Y.extend(EventList, Y.Plugin.Base, {
        render: function() {
        insertEventList.call(this);
    }
```

Admittedly, YUI3 confuses me, and I would prefer other libraries, but I don't have a choice in this situation. There's likely one thing that I've just completely looked over.

Thanks guys

Comment: Just off the top of my head, don't you need to call `init()` or something similar after creating the object?

Comment: Can you post the code that uses the plugin? You seem to have created it, but not actually 'plugged' it into anything! :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I haven't responded sooner. I was looking into the init business, because that really does make sense. There's a whole lot of code that's irrelevant to this plugin, but I do have a `YUI.use("node", "node-load", "events", "anim", "transition", "history", function(Y) { ... }` 

There is no init for the events otherwise... Or I guess EventList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used YUI3 plugins before and they are a bit difficult to grasp, but I'll try to help if I can. Once you've created the plugin, which, from what I can tell, you've already done so successfully, you plug it into an object somewhere else in your code:

`someObj.plug(Y.Plugin.EventList, cfg);`

After that, you can access the plugin's methods from within the object's plugin namespace. In your case you'd do this like so:

`someObj.EventList.render();`

Hopefully I'm understanding your question correctly and I hope that helps clear some stuff up for you. Good luck! :)

Comment: So, just `var eventsPanel`, and then `eventsPanel.plug(Y.Plugin.EventList, cfg);`, then `eventsPanel.render();`? And if I have nothing to configure, having cfg in there won't do anything wacky?

Comment: Right. Actually, if you don't have any configuration attributes to pass in, you can just leave that out entirely: `eventsPanel.plug(Y.Plugin.EventList);`
You only need the cfg object if your plugin needs it, which it looks like yours doesn't.

Comment: wait, actually, the second part is missing something. It would be `eventsPanel.EventList.render();`. The plugin's methods will be in the plugin's namespace in the object, not in the object itself.

Comment: Oh, nice catch. For some reason I was getting 'eventsPanel is null', I tried setting it to the div I'm inserting into... Now I'm getting eventsPanel.plug is not a function. Hmm... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working. 

`var eventlist = $("#insert-eventlist");
   eventlist.plug(Y.Plugin.EventList);
   eventlist.EventList.render();`

I just ended up doing it at the bottom of the YUI.use {}. It's seemingly the same as what I had before, and only a few lines lower, but now it works. Actually, I'm realizing that one of those lines had something to do with the panel I'm inserting these into. Likely where the mixup was occuring.

Comment: Ah... Again, my fault. You'd plug it into the div that you want to populate using a YUI node. So if the div you wanted to populate was `<div id="populate-me"></div>`, you'd call:

`var div = Y.one('#populate-me');
div.plug(Y.Plugin.EventList);
div.EventList.render();`

Sorry about all the mis-information, but I think this time, it should actually work. ;)

Comment: It's working great. Just need to do some styling and it'll be perfect. Thanks again. I tried to upvote your answer but I can't since I'm a new user and don't have 15 reputation yet. What a bunch of jerks! heh

Anyway, since I can't upvote yet, I'm just making this post to let you know I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Haha, no prob. I still get rep for you accepting my answer. :P Happy coding!